# STM32 FDCAN Bootloader Strange Problem in Write data

Tags: flash, arm, stm32, bootloader, can-bus

I have worked with STM32h723 arm processor FDCAN bootloader. but I faced a strange problem in writing data into flash.
I can successfully make processor go to FDCAN bootloader and get responses from it but can't write data in some address.(see images)

for example, I can write data in address 0x08000000 and 0x08000004 but I can't write data in 0x08000008 or 0x0800000C. it will filled with 0 or remains 0xFFFFFFFF.

I read AN2606 and AN5405 ST's documentation but has no results. also, I tested the bootloader in many ways and always it responds with ACK message, but data hasn't written in some addresses. Also I have worked on CAN bootloader on STM32F4 and that was so straightforward  and worked perfectly but FDCAN bootloader in STM32H723 has painful behavior.
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM8He.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Drq8.png)

Comment: Flash write timings? Notice the number of words written correctly and incorrectly is consistent. Check write width. Reference manual, page 154 mentions write buffer and "Write wrap burst must not cross 32-byte aligned address boundaries to target exactly one Flash word" (read there for more context). Check if there aren't issues with any of those.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I will check it. @Ilya

Comment: It could also be a pointer increment bug. Try writing some fixed values like 0x00000000 0x11111111 0x22222222 0x33333333 ... just to see what gets written where, what values are skipped or not skipped. Also, if you need to check it byte-wise, you can use something like 0x11223344.